# что делать если не импортируются русские данны?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Импортирую данные через DBeaver(Postgres)

```
Error occurred during batch insert
(you can disable batch insert in order to skip particular rows).

Причина:
 SQL Error [22003]: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO public.standard ("number",fio)
    VALUES (79013657371,'��������') was aborted: ОШИБКА: целое вне диапазона  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
```

В самом файле:

```
79013657371,Ярослава
```

Ему не нравится русские сиволы я так полагаю, но какую кодировку и на что поставить?

Comment: Начните с проверки кодировки самого импортируемого файла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
src/backend/po/ru.po-msgid "integer out of range"
src/backend/po/ru.po:msgstr "целое вне диапазона"
```

Кириллица определённо не должна вызывать ошибку `integer out of range`. Проверьте тип данных поля `number`, подходящий ли у него тип данных. Тип `integer` однозначно не годится.

Затем смотрите, нет ли в таблице каких триггеров или generated columns или default nextval, не вызывают ли переполнение int какие-то другие условия.